# Prove the sentence by induction

Tags: induction

Prove by induction that $$3^m > (m+1) \cdot \sin m,\quad\forall m \geq 0$$

I need to get to $> (m+2) \sin (m+1)$.

The sine $m$ and $m+1$ oscillate differently, I can't make it smaller.

Comment: The thought process here should be something like: this inequality is massively, massively true. If I need to make it easier, I can afford to make some *very* crude approximations. What approximations can I make on $\sin$ and on $m+1$ to make them into more exponential- and induction-friendly expressions?

Comment: @PatrickStevens In proofs by induction do you always need to use the induction hypothesis? Because that way it looks like you don't need it.

Comment: Yes, a proof by induction is characterised by using an induction hypothesis. However, you don't have to use the first induction hypothesis that springs to mind! You can prove something else by induction, and then show that what you proved implies what you were meant to prove.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $-1\le \sin m\le 1$, let instead prove the stronger

$$3^m > m+1 \ge (m+1) \cdot \sin m$$

Comment: $3^k (k+1) \cdot \sin k$, $k>0$ I didn't figure out how to use sine to get to $3^{k+1} > (k+2) \sin (k+1)$

Comment: @Behemooth We can prove by induction that $3^m>m+1$ since $m+1\ge (m+1)\sin m$, in this way we can ignore $\sin m$.

Comment: If you desire keep $\sin m$, in the induction hypothesis we have that $3^k>k+1\ge (k+1)\sin k$ and then $3^{k+1}=3\cdot 3^k>3(k+1)>(k+2)>(k+2)\sin(k+1)$